# A button that creates an imageview that is draggable

Tags: android, android-studio

Beginner at android dev here, I want to create an android game but this function is putting a roadblock on progress.

I want to create a button that when clicked will put a new imageview in the middle and that imageview is draggable anywhere on the activity.

I've tried looking up draggable imageview but I haven't seen any relevant results and I don't really understand how to create a new view because you can't clone a view and the process is complicated to create a new view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageView and add to them a drag listener using method .OnDragListener { view, dragEvent -> }